# Having a few troubles as a first time user

Tags: dual-boot

As the title suggests, I am new to Ubuntu and this forum - so please excuse my ignorance.

I am a long time Mac user who has also been Dual Booting Windows for a while and decided it was time to give Linux a try. I used (https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-macos) to install it, using a bootable USB stick.

Everything went pretty well at first, but it seems to have tumbled from there on. Forewarning,I designated plenty of storage in the partition that I created. Now, 9/10 times when I boot up my Mac (holding the Option key) and choose the "EFI Boot" option, I am not given the option to launch into Ubuntu. Rather, on a black and white screen I am able to:
 *install (as if for the first time)
*try Ubuntu without installing
*check for Disc updates

The screen I'm looking for (as some of you likely know) is  a purple screen with the "Ubuntu" option, which just allows me to boot right up.

I'm not sure why I encounter this error, but often times restarting my machine or using the "trial" option fix the problem.

Also! When I am able to boot up, it seems to have trouble connecting to my Wireless Network. I checked the box to remember the password, but it seems that even with the password it just tries to connect for a while before giving up and asking me to try again. I am very sure that my password is correct, as sometimes I will be booted off of my connection in Ubuntu while simply browsing Reddit.

I know I haven't provided a whole lot details about my issues, but if you need more information I can do my best to provide it for you! Thanks in advance for any help you can provide, this community seems pretty sound to me.

Comment: The way this site works, you should post **one** issue per question, with all the details concerning that issue - see [How do I ask a good question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @steeldriver my mistake, won't happen again.

Answer (score 1):

As you're a first time user i'll try to solve your problem while still teaching you a little about the startup of a computer so that you can understand the conceptual mistake you're making, which is pretty normal given your experience.The bootable usb is an option available that allows you to try and install virtually all linux distros, having that in mind, let's start:

1- Once you hit the **power button** on your computer the first program that is executed is called BIOS and completes the POST (power on self test) the screen and the keyboard are turned on and the memory is tested.

2- the **boot loader**, there are two main different types of systems: the ones that use the BIOS/MBR method or the EFI/UEFI machines, What these protocols do is basically search bootable partitions on the hard disk

3- the **grub** program (there are others this is the default bootloader for ubuntu) which displays the different bootable option that are found on the hard disk.

**conclusions:**

You have the ubuntu iso in a usb stick and when you tell the system to boot from the usb the grub program will only scan the given usb and not look  on the hard disk of the computer, that's why you cannot find the rest of your partitions (windows and mac).

**What to do:**

In order to allow the grub to display the rest of the partitions you will have to install ubuntu on your computer and setting up the partitions with the rest of the OS's. I leave you a link to that topic:

Comment: thank you very much for all of that info, I think I've got a better grasp on what's going on during this process. However, my problem isn't that I can't find the rest of my partitions. When booting up I am given three options. Mac, Windows and EFI Boot. My problem is that when I choose EFI Boot, 9/10 times it will just prompt me to reinstall Ubuntu as if I never had before. This can be fixed by booting into Ubuntu as a "trial" run, and then restarting the system without holding the "option" key, which will just boot into Ubuntu like normal.

Comment: It looks like there was a misunderstanding. The triple boot is not a common option, but the possibility exists, i've found a link on the internet (a bit outdated in terms of the OS's mentiened) that explains the process in detail, check if you missed an step: http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.22/22.11/TripleBoot/index.html